# Importing a .pl file

Tags: perl, import

I was wondering how to import a Perl file to a script. I experimented with use, require and do, but nothing seems to work for me. This is how I did it with require:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require {
 (equations)
}

print "$x1\n";
```

Is it possible to code for substituting a value (I get in my script) into `equations.pl`, then have my script use an equation defined in `equations.pl` to calculate another value? How do I do this?

Comment: Is the `equations.pl` given or can you change its content? If you can change it, why not put the equation in a [`sub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) and just call it like any other function?

Comment: I think you need to give an example of the sort of value and equation you are expecting, and why the equation needs to be in a separate file. It sounds like `equations.pl` needs to define a subroutine which you can then just call in your main program, passing the value as a parameter.

Comment: equations.pl has 28 equations, and I defined them there in order to keep myself sane when looking at my script. So the problem is that I am using some loops to determine the values of two variables, and I want to substitute a value I get into equations.pl and get another value out of equations.pl.

Answer (score 6):

You can require a .pl file, which will then execute the code in it, but in order to access variables, you need a package, and either "use" instead of require (the easy way) or via Exporter.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html

Simple example: here's the stuff you want to import, name it Example.pm:

```
package Example;

our $X = 666;

1;  # packages need to return true.
```

And here's how to use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Example;

print $Example::X;
```

This presumes Example.pm is in the same directory, or the top level of an @INC directory.

Answer (score 3):

**equations.pm** file:

```
package equations;

sub add_numbers {
  my @num = @_;
  my $total = 0;
  $total += $_ for @num;
  $total;
}

1;
```

**test.pl** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use equations;

print equations::add_numbers(1, 2), "\n";
```

---

***output:***

```
3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't import a *file*. You can execute a file and import *symbols* (variables and subs) from it. See [Perl Modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) in perlmod.

Answer (score 0):

You've given very few details about `equations.pl`, but if the input can be given via a command line argument, then you can [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a pipe:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $variable; #the variable that you will get from equations.pl
my $input=5; #the input into equations.pl

open (my $fh,"-|","perl equations.pl $input") or die $!;

while(my $output=<$fh>)
{
  chomp($output); #remove trailing newline
  $variable=$output;
}

if(defined($variable))
{
  print "It worked! \$variable=$variable\n";
}
else
{
  print "Nope, \$variable is still undefined...\n";
}
```

If this is the body of `equations.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo=$ARGV[0];
$foo++;
print "$foo\n";
```

Then the code above outputs:

```
It worked! $variable=6
```

Comment: Only as hacky as the OP's mysterious `equations.pl` file.  Would you call *nix pipes "hacky" as well?

Comment: No, of course not. They are a great tool but seem the wrong tool here. I think the other answers show the way better approach.

Comment: Usually when someone thinks about importing a script file, they are thinking about how to include functions and potentially data.  Perl modules work in this manner.  This solution could work for functions if there is an eval used, but that only makes it even more hacky.